# Where to find more logs to troubleshoot systemd configuration?

Tags: systemd

Three weeks later, I still have not been able to figure out why this systemd timed service will not run. Rather than list all the research I have done, I will simply show what I am working towards.

If someone could point me in the direction of where to look to find the problem, I would be very appreciative.

## Goal

*Grab a screenshot with Flameshot once a minute.*

## The Bits and Pieces

### Bash script

Output from `test@test-i3:~$ cat /usr/share/screenmonitor/screenMonitor.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/flameshot full --path /home/test/.screenshots
exit
```

### Systemd Service Unit

Output from `test@test-i3:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/screenMonitor.service`...

```
[Unit]
Description=Capture screenshots at a given interval
Wants=screenMonitor.timer

[Service]
Type=simple 
User=test
Group=test
ExecStart=/usr/share/screenmonitor/screenMonitor.bash

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Systemd Timer Unit

Output from `test@test-i3:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/screenMonitor.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Capture screenshots at a given interval
Requires=screenMonitor.service

[Timer]
Unit=screenMonitor.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

## Troubleshooting

### Problem

*The expected screenshots are NOT showing up in `/home/test/.screenshots`*

### Looking for the problem

1. Does the bash script run manually? Yes, this DOES create a screenshot in the expected folder: `test@test-i3:~$ /usr/share/screenmonitor/screenMonitor.bash`
2. Is the service being triggered? and running successfully? Yes, logs show the service is running successfully at the expected time interval.

```
Apr 11 08:06:31 test-i3 systemd[1]: Started Capture screenshots at a given interval.
Apr 11 08:06:31 test-i3 systemd[1]: screenMonitor.service: Succeeded.
Apr 11 08:07:31 test-i3 systemd[1]: Started Capture screenshots at a given interval.
Apr 11 08:07:31 test-i3 systemd[1]: screenMonitor.service: Succeeded.
Apr 11 08:08:31 test-i3 systemd[1]: Started Capture screenshots at a given interval.
Apr 11 08:08:31 test-i3 systemd[1]: screenMonitor.service: Succeeded.
```

### Question

So the script works and the service shows to have successfully run, but no screenshots are showing up. Where do I turn next to track down why the systemd service is not returning the expected screenshots?

## Edit - adding more complete logs

Where do I go to find that this systemd unit is indeed running as a system task rather than in a user session?

@MarcusMüller says "*system* tasks cannot know the settings necessary to... run on your user session." I expect he is correct.

But I am still not seeing it in the logs **and** the systemd unit is set to run as the user.

Exporting a more verbose set of logs (like @foshyboy [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699206/521835)) shows the systemd unit running successfully at the expected time interval.

```
test@test:~$ sudo journalctl -u screenMonitor.service -o verbose | tail -n57
Mon 2022-05-02 15:14:11.634017 -03 [s=54677f9d50e54de79146a6d96eddd5d3;i=dbd;b=7847eb41c0ef46eeb98aab83c90091c7;m=5457c5970;t=5de0b5bea2f81;x=1377c5d4806eaaf]
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=systemd
    UNIT=screenMonitor.service
    _TRANSPORT=journal
    _PID=1
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _COMM=systemd
    _EXE=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
    _CMDLINE=/sbin/init
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _SELINUX_CONTEXT=unconfined
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/init.scope
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=init.scope
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=-.slice
    _BOOT_ID=7847eb41c0ef46eeb98aab83c90091c7
    _MACHINE_ID=279c8612447944b6925e3f6aa4adf4b8
    _HOSTNAME=test
    CODE_FILE=../src/core/job.c
    CODE_LINE=950
    CODE_FUNC=job_log_done_status_message
    MESSAGE=Started Capture screenshots at a given interval.
    JOB_TYPE=start
    JOB_RESULT=done
    MESSAGE_ID=39f53479d3a045ac8e11786248231fbf
    JOB_ID=50117
    INVOCATION_ID=40e5dd06027f4196a7b07a91a96ce730
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1651515251634017
Mon 2022-05-02 15:14:11.656875 -03 [s=54677f9d50e54de79146a6d96eddd5d3;i=dbe;b=7847eb41c0ef46eeb98aab83c90091c7;m=5457cb2b5;t=5de0b5bea88c6;x=6c97e2c69c2188c5]
    PRIORITY=6
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=3
    CODE_FILE=../src/core/unit.c
    CODE_LINE=5487
    CODE_FUNC=unit_log_success
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=systemd
    MESSAGE_ID=7ad2d189f7e94e70a38c781354912448
    UNIT=screenMonitor.service
    MESSAGE=screenMonitor.service: Succeeded.
    _TRANSPORT=journal
    _PID=1
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _COMM=systemd
    _EXE=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
    _CMDLINE=/sbin/init
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _SELINUX_CONTEXT=unconfined
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/init.scope
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=init.scope
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=-.slice
    _BOOT_ID=7847eb41c0ef46eeb98aab83c90091c7
    _MACHINE_ID=279c8612447944b6925e3f6aa4adf4b8
    _HOSTNAME=test
    INVOCATION_ID=40e5dd06027f4196a7b07a91a96ce730
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1651515251656875
```

Comment: Wrong tool for the job: a systemd *system* task cannot know the settings necessary to let your screen capturing tool run on your user session.

Answer (score 1):

To see a more detailed Output from `journalctl` you can use:

1. `journalctl -o verbose`
2. `journalctl -o json-pretty`

To to additionally filter the Output of the Journal to a specific Service use:

1. `journalctl -u screenMonitor.service -o verbose`
2. `journalctl -u screenMonitor.service -o json-pretty`